# How to specify module in namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, routes, namespaces

I want to do something like:

```
namespace :dashboard do
  get 'speed'
  get 'engine'
  get 'oil'
  get 'errors', :to => 'warn_system#errors', :module => false
end
```

Only errors link to another controller.

```
dashboard_speed  GET  /dashboard/speed(.:format)  dashboard#speed
dashboard_oil    GET  /dashboard/oil(.:format)    dashboard#oil
dashboard_engine GET  /dashboard/engine(.:format) dashboard#engine
dashboard_errors GET  /dashboard/errors(.:format) dashboard/warn_system#errors {:module=>false}
```

For the last record, I want it to be

```
dashboard_errors GET  /dashboard/errors(.:format)  warn_system#errors
```

What shall I do?
I am using Rails 3 if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To route to a different controller within a namespace specify the absolute path to the controller. If the warn_system controller is in the root namespace use:

```
namespace :dashboard do
  get 'errors', :to => '/warn_system#errors'
end
```

Update:

Based on your comment it looks like you want to use:

```
namespace :dashboard do
  get 'errors', :to => '/dashboard/warn_system#errors'
end
```

Comment: from my side, it shows "dashboard//warn_system#errors".

Comment: The update is not what I want. Refer to the following answer, it seems that your original answer works in Rails 4 but not working in Rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 3, try this:

```
  scope '/dashboard' do
    get 'errors', :to => 'warn_system#errors'
  end
```

Comment: That looks like an alternative. You are saying add both `scope` and `namespace` for `dashboard`. I prefer using only `namespace` if possible.

Comment: It works with `:namespace` in Rails 4.x.x as suggested by previous answer but not in Rails 3. I think it doesn't hurt to use `scope` for this one route, or upgrade to Rails 4.